# Rails Will Paginate problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I´m paginating with the `will_paginate` plugin.

I have a popup that adds `@products` when the user clicks the button `Add` via an Ajax request.

Note: The `@products` is paginated

In Ajax Request I update the product-list :

```
 ids = params[:accessories][:id].join(" and id <> ")
 @products = Product.find_by_sql("select * from products where id <> #{ids}")
```

However if I use: `@products = Product.find_by_sql("select * from products where id <> #{ids}").paginate`

it returns identical array.

So how I could paginate the array again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using find_by_sql method?

May be you can write something like this:

```
ids = params[:accessories][:id].join(",")
@products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :conditions => ["not (id in (?))", ids])
```

also conditions you can move to product model and replace it with scope(Rails 3) or named_scope(Rails 2).

Answer (score 2):

Already tried:

```
@products = Product.paginate :conditions => conditions
```

Comment: Thanks The two answers are solutions